Can a gearbox for a brushless motor help to reduce propeller diameter on quadcopter?
If the required propeller diameter is too large for a drone, can we use a gearbox with some gear ratio like 4:1 to get a same thrust with a smaller propeller?  Will the efficiency be lower?
If it is possible, I would like to see the equation to calculate the output thrust for the propeller with a brushless motor connected to a gearbox and how it depends on the gear ratio.

you will usually choose propeller diameter from aerodynamic efficiency considerations, before choosing the motor. A smaller prop is always lower power efficiency for the same thrust as a large one. If it's only used in liftoff before transitioning to wing-assisted flight, then you can tolerate very low power efficiency for a brief time. If it cruises in hover, then you need all the efficiency you can get.

I spent a year studying propeller cross sections from the old NACA, which preceded NASA. I can just say that the issues are not simple. There are thousands of variations and the design of the propeller isn't a constant if you change things like this. Everything matters. There's a lot of experimental result available to help. But it takes studying to use it wisely. This means there are simple and ignorant answers which will go only go only so far. And nuanced answers which will get much more out of a situation. But a simple equation will be the ignorant approach only. Propeller design matters.

How can I calculate the thrust of a propeller? (Aviation stack exchange)

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about Electrical Engineering.

Output torque equals to the input torque multiplied by gearbox ratio -p and efficiency.
$$T_{out}=\eta\cdot p\cdot T_{in}$$
Output power equals to input power multiplied by efficiency:
$$P_{out}=\eta\cdot P_{in}$$
Output speed equals to input speed divided by gearbox ratio
Of course the efficiency will be lower, see gearbox datasheet. But you could swap the BLDC with other BLDC with higher torque and lower speed to achieve the goal, a quality gearbox is more expensive than BLDC.
$$\omega_{out}=\dfrac{\omega_{in}}{p}$$

So thrust of large propeller without a gearbox ~= thrust of 4x smaller propeller with 4:1 gearbox?

@Rooter No, because the propeller is a quadratic load, The resultant torque is where load torque (propeller) and motor torque intersect if you would draw the characteristics torque VS speed.
